# why does this mysql error causes nodejs to crash instead of going to the catch function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a mysql statement that creates an entry, it has a `.then` function and a `.catch` function, but when the following error occurs:

`TypeError('Bind parameters must not contain undefined. To pass SQL NULL specify JS null');`

the server crashes instead of answering a 500 like defined in the `.catch` function

Note: I'm using the `mysql2` library from npm with promises (`require('mysql2/promise');`)

Here's the code that calls it (`req.params.account_name` is `undefined`):

```
const CREATE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT =
  'INSERT INTO `Accounts` (`account_token`, `account_name`) VALUES (?, ?)'

try {
  mysqlConnectionPool.execute(CREATE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT, [
    account_token, account_name
  ])
  .then(() => {
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ token: account_token }))
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    debug(1, "error while trying to create account:", e)
    res.status(500).end("Internal Server Error")
  })
} catch(e) {
  debug(1, "error while trying to create account:", e)
  res.status(500).end("Internal Server Error")
}
```

Comment: TBH, I think this is a bug in how `mysql2` wraps `mysql` with promises.

Comment: Here's a PoC that shows that the error cannot be caught by either a `.catch` or a `try/catch` (using `mysql2@1.6.1`): https://gist.github.com/robertklep/a85560c2e4c0e76a038c6df4ecb729df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, @Quentine was close to the right thing...

It is "sort of" a bug in `mysql2`,
i use sort-of because https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/902 suggests the development team of `mysql2` is o.k. with it.

it is an issue with the way mysql2.pool passes the call to the created connection, which does not pass the exception to the wrapping promise.

I ended up making my own wrapping function to create the connection + call execute wrapped in proper promise handling.

```
import mysql = require('mysql2');
private async queryDB(query:string, useExecute: boolean = false, ...args:any[]) : Promise<any[]>
    {
        return new Promise<any[]>((resolve, reject)=>{
            for(var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
            {
                if(args[i]===undefined)
                    args[i] = null;
            }
            this.dbPool.getConnection((err, conn)=>{
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                
                let cb = function(err: mysql.QueryError, results: any[], fields: mysql.FieldPacket[]) {
                    conn.release();
                    if(err)
                    {
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve(results);
                }
                if(useExecute)
                    conn.execute(query, args, cb);
                else
                    conn.query(query, args, cb);                
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the wrapper function in your answer (or at least the important parts of it)?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqlConnectionPool.execute` is throwing the exception *before* creating a promise.

i.e. the exception is not thrown from within the promise.

To catch it you would need to `try {} catch (e) {}` around the call to `mysqlConnectionPool.execute`.

Comment: I surrounded the entire thing with try catch and it still crashes. I'll edit my question with the revised code. See if you can tell me why

Comment: @TomKlino Yes Quentin is just right, The error is thrown while trying to bind values on the SQL statement. The Promise has to do about an executed statement but until reaching that point there are several stages like preparing the statement, binding the values and finally executing it which will create the Promise.

Comment: @GeorgeTavantzopoulos in that case, it should be possible to catch the error using `try/catch` around the `execute` method, which it isn't (possibly because there's a few calls to `process.nextTick` inside the connection pool code that are causing the error to be thrown asynchronously)

Answer (score -1):

Well,

I'm guessing that you are using the standard [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package which it seems not supporting Promises, instead, it accepts a standard node callback `function(err, results, fields) {}` as an argument of the execute method.

So since you haven't defined a valid callback the script will just throw an exception.

Comment: no. I'm using `const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');`

Comment: @TomKlino please add that information to your question.